# Maximum value of two parameters function

Tags: functions

How can I find the maximum value of that function?

$y(s,t) = \frac{as}{(b + s)} \cdot \frac{t}{(c + t)}$

Comment: Would you care to tell us where is $y$ defined?

Comment: y is a real number. a,b,c are constants and s,t are real parameters

Comment: I think $y$ is a function, right?
If it is, what's its domain?

Comment: Why can not we put $s=-b$ or $t=-c$ if $a>0?$

Comment: s is in interval (0,7), t - (0.1, 1) and y - (0, 0.1).

Comment: y is a function of a growth speed in chemistry, s and t are concentrations of a substrate and the concentration of oxygen.